# C# MemoryStream is larger than FileStream

Tags: c#, compression, filestream, memorystream, deflate

I've a method to compress a byte-array. I used a memorystream and a filestream for testing. the result from the memorystream is larger, even if its the same method, can anyone explain why?

```
public byte[] DeflateCompress(byte[] data2Compress)
{
    using (FileStream _fileToCompress = File.Create("_deflatecompressed.bin"))
    {
        using (DeflateStream _compressionStream = new DeflateStream(_fileToCompress, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            _compressionStream.Write(data2Compress, 0, data2Compress.Length);
            _compressionStream.Close();
        }
    }

    return File.ReadAllBytes("_deflatecompressed.bin");
}

public byte[] DeflateCompress(byte[] data2Compress)
{
    using (MemoryStream _memStreamCompress = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (DeflateStream _defalteStreamCompress = new DeflateStream(_memStreamCompress, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            _defalteStreamCompress.Write(data2Compress, 0, data2Compress.Length);
            _defalteStreamCompress.Close();
        }

        return _memStreamCompress.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

If I write the output byte-array to a file, then the one created with memorystream is larger.

Comment: use `.ToArray` instead of `.GetBuffer`  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx) warns of this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`MemoryStream.GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) will return the full internal buffer, which can be larger than the data. It's resized in chunks as needed. When you exceed the buffer capacity, the internal buffer size is doubled.

If you need to convert the `MemoryStream` to a byte array containing only the data, use [`MemoryStream.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx). It will create a new array of the adequate size, and copy the relevant buffer contents into it.

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) puts it:

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused. For example, if the string `"test"` is written into the `MemoryStream` object, the length of the buffer returned from `GetBuffer` is `256`, not `4`, with `252` bytes unused. To obtain only the data in the buffer, use the `ToArray` method; however, `ToArray` creates a copy of the data in memory.

The `GetBuffer` function is useful in the case when you want to read a chunk from the buffer, and you don't care if the size doesn't exactly match. `ToArray` is slower as it has to copy the whole buffer contents on each call, while `GetBuffer` will simply return a reference to the buffer.

For instance, `GetBuffer` can be useful if you use methods such as [`Stream.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write.aspx):

```
public abstract void Write(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

There are many places in the framework with such overloads that take a buffer but only process a chunk of it.

Comment: +1 Alternatively you can use `GetBuffer()` with `Length` to avoid extra copy.

Answer (score 1):

The MemoryStream is using a byte array internally. Which gets doubled when needed.

So likely it has a TON of not used bytes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Back to school? The question is - read the title: "C# MemoryStream is larger than FileStream". I explain why. That is an answer.

Comment: With so much reputation, you should know better and provide better quality answers...

Comment: No need to be nasty. And I most certainly didn't drop out from school.