# Content-Length of the response header is less than the actual file size

Tags: c#, http, header, http-headers

I'm trying to get the size of an image before downloading it. I send a `HEAD` request to the image link and the value of Content-Length in response header is `307186`.
But when I download the image, I get `518176` bytes. I've tried disabling the compression (By setting 'Accept-Encoding' in request header to 'Identity') but Content-Length doesn't change.
Even when I send a `GET` request to download the image, Content-Length and the actual file size are different.
the code I'm using to get the image:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "HEAD";
var response = request.GetResponse();
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream()!).BaseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
var buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
```

Comment: Please show relevant code. `HEAD` requests don't work well on many servers, and are generally pointless anyway: if you want something just request it and deal with it, rather than making two calls.

Comment: @Charlieface The problem is even when I send a GET request, Content-Length and the file size doesn't match

Comment: `memoryStream.GetBuffer()` returns the backing array, which may be larger. Use `memoryStream.ToArray()` if you want an exact array. Alternatively check `memoryStream.Length`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# MemoryStream is larger than FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976233/c-sharp-memorystream-is-larger-than-filestream)

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you! Using ToArray() instead of GetBuffer() did solve the problem!. I really didn't think that the problem might be with how memoryStream turns the data to an array. You saved me a lot of time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You should be able to accept that link with a button above. Note also that you are missing `using` on a bunch of objects there, so they won't get disposed correctly, and also `WebRequest` is effectively deprecated and you should use `HttpClient` instead. You might also want to consider *why* you want a `MemoryStream` and whether you couldn;t instead pass the original stream through.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Charlieface's comment, the answer from [Lucas Trzesniewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764814/lucas-trzesniewski) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976233/c-sharp-memorystream-is-larger-than-filestream) thread :

`MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` will return the full internal buffer, which can be larger than the data. It's resized in chunks as needed. When you exceed the buffer capacity, the internal buffer size is doubled.

If you need to convert the MemoryStream to a byte array containing only the data, use `MemoryStream.ToArray()`. It will create a new array of the adequate size, and copy the relevant buffer contents into it.